# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library

Tags: java, pentaho, spoon

Hi This is the error i'm receiving running spoon pentaho on CentOS, i really don't know what to do, i tried installing the missing packages but it can't find them.

```
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    no swt-pi-gtk-4332 in java.library.path
    no swt-pi-gtk in java.library.path
    /home/daniele/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi-gtk-4332.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Can't load library: /home/daniele/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi-gtk.so
```